# Accessing sharepoint webservice from ASP

Tags: sharepoint, asp-classic

I want to access sharepoint list webservice from classic ASP Page. I am creating the soap xml format and trying to call the webservice url, like this

```
Dim http ,soap

soap = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
soap =soap & "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>"
soap =soap & "<soap12:Body>"
soap =soap & "<GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>"
soap =soap & "<listName>Posts</listName>"
soap =soap & "<viewName></viewName>"
soap =soap & "<query></query>"
soap =soap & "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Modified'/><FieldRef Name='DefaultViewUrl'/><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Author'/><FieldRef Name='Name'/><FieldRef Name='Body'/><FieldRef Name='NumComments'/><FieldRef Name='DefaultViewUrl'/></ViewFields>"
soap =soap & "<rowLimit>5</rowLimit>"
soap =soap & "<QueryOptions><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><DateInUtc>FALSE</DateInUtc></QueryOptions>"
soap =soap & "</GetListItems>"
soap =soap & "</soap12:Body>"
soap =soap & "</soap12:Envelope>"

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "POST", URL, False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;  charset=utf-8"
http.send(soap)
```

But i am getting the error like "An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. 
If you are the system administrator..."

Do I need to pass any authentication or something else is the problem?.

Comment: What's the URL you're posting to? You don't need to share the host name, but the rest of the path.

Comment: this is the url which i am using, "Blogs/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"

Comment: That could be the authentication missing. You cannot access the SharePoint API as an anonymous user.

You could use an ADO Connector for SharePoint, http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/. Combining it with a WCF service like the Camelot SharePoint Integration Service you'll be up and running with your ASP Classic integration in no time.

Comment: Hi

Know that this post is becoming old by now, but just wanted to paste a link for ASP classic -> SharePoint using COM+. http://blog.bendsoft.com/2012/09/introduction-to-com-in-camelot-net-connector-2/.

Comment: before any authentication, you should add the SOAPAction header which is required to identify what method you want to call

Answer (score 1):

If you are not under the SharePoint site, the problem is you are getting denied access. SharePoint is expecting a cookie or NTLM authorization to do this.

Can you relay a little more?

David Sterling
Sterling International Consulting Group
davidmsterling.blogspot.com
www.sharepoint-blog.com

Comment: When I am trying to access the sharepoint webservice through Javascript I am getting the result but the problem is it prompting a message like " This page is accessing information that is not under its control.(because it is cross domain access.)". I dont want to show that popup so i am trying to access the webservice on server side.